# Make a counter, that counts cell change

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a cell, let us call it `A1`, that contains an `IF` function.
Cell `A1` changes between two types of text:

1. Healthy
2. Injured

What I want is a counter in for example `B1` that counts how many times `A1` has changed to "injured". In more simple terms, I want to add 1 to `B1` each time `A1 = "Injured"`.

Answer (score 1):

The change of a cell, by a formula, will not trigger an `onEdit` trigger via a Google Apps Script. Therefore you need to use *that* particular cell, that triggers the formula and thus the counter.

You can use the following script to create a counter.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "C2") {
    var sCounter = e.source.getRange("B2");
    var counter = sCounter.getValue();

    if(counter === 0) {
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter ++;
    }
    sCounter.setValue(counter);  
  }  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Counter](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFM2OUgzRl9YWTNXV3NWYjJfLXBuSlE&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

That's not really something which spreadsheets do well (in jargon, they're declarative, rather than procedural).

You can probably write a script which executes each time there is a "commit" action on that cell and adds 1 to the existing value in another cell where you keep the most recent count of "has become injured" - and I'd say that someone with coding skills will show you how to do that very shortly.

But the question makes me think that you're trying to do more with a spreadsheet than you really should.    Or maybe you should be keeping some history rather than just over-typing the current value?   That way, you could do a sum on the history values.   To me, this would be a "safer" way of working, because you would have an audit trail of why your counter has its current value, and a way to fix up any problems.

Under the "run a script on value change" model, if someone changes A1 to Injured, then says "oops, that was a mistake" and changes it back to healthy - the count will be incremented anyway.  Or if someone accidentally changes the value of the cell where you have the count stored, there is no way to re-construct the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have been warned that this is not really a good idea but it is possible with just a formula, provided you set the sheet's calculation to *Iterative calculation* On and *Max. number of iterations* to `1`. Then, when `Healthy` is in A1 in B1:

```
=if(A1="Injured",1,0)+B1
```